# Bypassing FormulaArray

Tags: excel, vba

I would like to use an array formula (the ones you need to enter through Ctrl+Shift+Enter in worksheets) without using Range.FormulaArray.

Do you think it is possible?
The formula I specifically want is:

```
    hello = WorksheetFunction.SMALL(WorksheetFunction.IF(MyRange<>0,MyRange),n)
```

Thank you all for your help.

Comment: It's unclear what you're asking for. You want to do something without doing it the way it's meant to be done?

Comment: I basically want to stock the value into a variable without having to bother managing a cell.

Comment: I want to use Small on MyRange without considering the zeros.

Answer (score 0):

Comparing array to 0 is not valid in VBA, but you can [`Evaluate`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/excel-vba/articles/worksheet-evaluate-method-excel?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) (`hello As Variant` for error values) :

```
hello = Sheet1.Evaluate("Small(If(" & MyRange.Address & "<>0, " & MyRange.Address & "), 2)")
```

Comment: The problem with this solution is that you can only get the minimum and you cannot access the n-th smallest element.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can use `IF` as a worksheet function in VBA.

However, if you have this:

[image]

You can do this:

```
Sub tester()

    Dim r, i

    r = ActiveSheet.Evaluate("IF(A1:A10=0,FALSE,A1:A10)")

    For i = LBound(r) To UBound(r)
        Debug.Print i, Application.Small(r, i)
    Next i

End Sub
```

and get this:

```
 1             1 
 2             2 
 3             3 
 4             5 
 5             6 
 6             7 
 7             8 
 8             9 
 9            Error 2036
 10           Error 2036
```

To translate your posted line of code:

```
hello = Application.Small(ActiveSheet.Evaluate("IF(A1:A10=0,FALSE,A1:A10)"), n)
```

Comment: Thank you for this solution even though it's not really what I was looking for.

Comment: In that case you might consider updating your question.  This is just a more elaborate version of your line of code.